# Maintain Same Thread usage for set of tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I need to create a `thread` based on demand (i.e. if new items/tasks found) and then have specific set of `items/tasks` running in the same thread always.

*eg:* If i have total 7 items/tasks currently then split the items and assign it to threads. Lets say we take 3 items in single thread, then,

`thread1` should be responsible for executing item1, item2, item3
`thread2` should be responsible for executing item4, item5, item6
`thread3` for item7 and for next 2 items if found.(should be able to fetch this `threadId` and add the next 2 items to this `thread`).

I tried going through docs/articles on `ThreadLocal` and `ThreadStatic` attribute but not getting exactly how to use these to implement my case here.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541495/what-is-cleanest-way-to-create-a-partitioned-thread-pool-in-c) exactly same to what i wanted but the solution doesn't seem to be a valid one.

Here is my code so far,

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<ItemInfo>> _itemToThreadMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<ItemInfo>>(); 

const int THREAD_PARTITION_SIZE = 10;

[ThreadStatic] List<ItemInfo> itemInfoList = new List<ItemInfo>();

 internal void CreateOrUpdateThreadMap()
        {
            try
            { 
                ItemInfo info = new ItemInfo(); // new item
                itemInfoList.Add(info);
                string threadId = _itemToThreadMap.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value.Count < THREAD_PARTITION_SIZE).Key;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(threadId))
                { 
                    _itemToThreadMap.TryGetValue(threadId, out List<ItemInfo> itemList); 
                    _itemToThreadMap.TryUpdate(threadId, itemInfoList, itemList); 
                }
                else
                { 
                    string newThreadId = $"thread_{_itemToThreadMap.Count + 1}";  

                    _printerToThreadMap.TryAdd(newThreadId, itemInfoList);
                    SpawnNewThread(newThreadId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Failed to create/update thread: ", ex);
            }
        } 

        internal void SpawnNewThread(string newThreadId)
        { 
            try
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    Thread itemThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MonitorJobsForThread));
                    printerThread.Name = newThreadId;
                    printerThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
            }
        }

  internal void MonitorJobsForThread()
  {
     // some long running job for this thread.
  }
```

Comment: It's rare to need to micro-manage threads these days, and often better to work at a higher level of abstraction. Unfortunately, your entire post is given over to threading mechanism so it's difficult to offer more concrete advise but in general, *don't* think threads.

Comment: Seems nuts to write your own thread management code when there are things like the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) in the runtime.

Comment: You might want to implement a custom `TaskScheduler`. Check out [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/ "ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour – #7 – Additional TaskSchedulers") article, and [this](https://github.com/donatasm/ParallelExtensionsExtras/tree/master/src/TaskSchedulers) source code. It's not trivial. Using the built-in [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    from n in Observable.Range(1, 9)
    let g = (n - 1) / 3
    group n by g into gn
    from r in
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new EventLoopScheduler(),
                els =>
                    from y in gn.ObserveOn(els)
                    select $"{y} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}")
    select r;
                    
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

When I run this I get this kind of output:

```
1 on thread 17
4 on thread 18
7 on thread 19
8 on thread 19
9 on thread 19
5 on thread 18
6 on thread 18
2 on thread 17
3 on thread 17
```

Note that 1 to 3 are on thread 17, 4 to 6 are on thread 18, and 7 to 9 are on thread 19.

The key things here are:

1. observable are like enumerables in that you can use LINQ to write queries. The difference is that observables push values to the consumers. It's like they are event-based.
2. `group n by g into gn` lets me take the series of values produces by `Observable.Range(1, 9)` and split them into 3 groups.
3. `EventLoopScheduler` creates a single thread scheduler that lasts until it is disposed.
4. The `Using` spins up a new `EventLoopScheduler` and then executes the `from`/`select` query on that scheduler, i.e. a single thread, finally disposing of each scheduler when the computation is finished.